# I am facing an issue with FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

First I want to tell you that my English is not too good so please compromise with me.
I am a beginner in React Native. I am working on project. In this project I am facing an issue. The issues is when I try to use FlatList or ScrollView to scroll the screen, the issue is irritating me. The half part of data is is disappeared. When I add color in FlatList it covers the half of the screen. I want to get rid off from this issue. I want that all the components should be show and when I want to scroll the screen the screen will easily scroll and no color disturb the content.

You can see the image here

[image: 1]

```
const SignUp: FC = () => {
    const data = [
        { key: 'Full Name', value: '' },
        { key: 'Email Address', value: '' },
        { key: 'Password', value: '' },
    ];
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(data);

    const handleInputChange = (value, index) => {
        const updatedFormData = [...formData];
        updatedFormData[index].value = value;
        setFormData(updatedFormData);
    };

    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={styles.inputSetting}>
            <Text style={styles.inputTxt}>{item.key}</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} value={item.value} onChangeText={(value) =>     handleInputChange(value, index)} />
        </View>
    );
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.bg}>
            <View style={styles.imgSetting}>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={require('../assets/WeHAP-1.png')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.SignUpSetting}>
                <Text style={styles.createAccountTxt}>Create Account</Text>
                <FlatList data={formData}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default SignUp;

......Styling......

bg: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
}
SignUpSetting: {
        backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
        flex: 1,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
        borderTopRightRadius: 40,
    },
    createAccountTxt: {
        color: '#000',
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        top: 40,
    },
    inputSetting: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        top: 60,
        left: 30,
        margin: 5,
    },
    inputTxt: {
        color: '#a1a1a1',
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        paddingRight: 250,
        top: 5,
        borderColor: '#229954',
       borderWidth: 0.6,
    },
```

Comment: Can you add the styles of `bg` to your question?

Comment: I added bg in my question.

Comment: I think the issue with the color is due to that the color is added to the `SignUpSetting` style class instead of the `bg`. Maybe for the scrolling the `top` styles have something to do with that